# Jquery executes more than it should

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to trigger `console.log` when someone clicks on the class `pane-2-0`. 
The whole code works, but when I try to click the element with the `pane-2-0` class it logs `F class send to console`, `V class send to console` and `K class send to console`. This doesn't happen with the rest of the code. When I click on `pane-2-1, .active` element it just logs `V class send to console`. What I'm trying to figure out is why the first one, `pane-2-0`, executes the three functions.

There are three main tabs/panes; `pane2-0`, `pane2-1` and `pane2-2`. The `responsive-tabs` are nested within the three panes. `#tablist1-tab1` to `#tablist1-tab3` are nested under `pane2-0` and `#tablist2-tab1` to `#tablist2-tab3` are nested under `pane2-2`.

The same thing happens when I try to click `#tablist1-tab1` to `#tablist1-tab3`. It logs the tab I clicked plus `V class send to log` and `K class send to log`.

It doesn't happen when I click `pane2-1` or `pane2-2`. Even logging `#tablist2-tab1` to `#tablist2-tab3` works perfectly. Adding `.active` to the selector doesn't help

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.pane-2-0').on('click', function(){
        console.log("F class send to console");
    });

    $('.pane-2-1, .active').on('click' , function(){
        console.log("V class send to console");
    });

    $('.pane-2-2, .active').on('click', function(){
        console.log("K class send to console");
    });

    $('.responsive-tabs').on('click', '#tablist1-tab1', function() {
        console.log("Financials Financials class send to console");
    });

    $('.responsive-tabs').on('click', '#tablist1-tab2', function() {
        console.log("Financials balans class send to console");
    });

    $('.responsive-tabs').on('click', '#tablist1-tab3', function() {
        console.log("Financials Cash Flow class send to console");
    });

    $('.responsive-tabs').on('click', '#tablist2-tab1', function() {
        console.log("KR Margins");
    });

    $('.responsive-tabs').on('click', '#tablist2-tab2', function() {
        console.log("KR Balans");
    });

    $('.responsive-tabs').on('click', '#tablist2-tab3', function() {
        console.log("KR gezondheid");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us a working example in http://jsfiddle.net, or at least an example of your HTML

Comment: Event Propagation. Use `event.stopPropagation();` in event handler, as the elements on which events are bound are nested.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Its kind of hard to so an example in jsfiddle or HTML, its built on a wordpress enviroment, so I can't really copy paste out the code.. sorry for that.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks the `event.stopPropagation();` fixed the nested issue, However, the pane2-0 still fires, all the functions. F class, V class and K class send to console.

Comment: Fixed the issue, the .active in the other classes messed with the code. Got rid of those class selectors and its working now. Thanks !